# How to get the exact full path to a file in Perl

Tags: perl

I only have a file name which is `myfile.txt` and I am not sure where it is saved. How can I get the exact full path where the file is stored?

I have tried

```
$string=`ls /abc/def/*/*/*/*/myfile.txt`;
```

Result: The full path is `/abc/def/ghi/jkl/mno/pqr/myfile.txt`

I able to get the full path by running `shell command` using the Perl script above. However, this took very long time to return the path. Is that a way to find the full path of the file by using Perl?

Comment: Please define "the full path". A file may have more than one. May it include symlinks?

Answer (score 29):

Well, if `myfile.txt` is actually a relative path to that file, there's a core module sub for that - [File::Spec->rel2abs()](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Spec.html#rel2abs%28%29):

```
  use File::Spec;
  ...
  my $rel_path = 'myfile.txt';
  my $abs_path = File::Spec->rel2abs( $rel_path ) ;
```

... and if you actually need to search through your directories for that file, there's File::Find... but I would go with shell `find / -name myfile.txt -print` command probably.

Comment: Hi Rainna.I,m sorry that it,s not relative path.I tried above code and the result return will be my <execution path>/myfile.txt

Comment: @Steven Yes, as `rel2abs` doesn't actually try to look for that file. How about using `find` command that I've given? Or perhaps you need strictly Perlish solution? ) Then File::Find is the way to go.

Answer (score 24):

You should use the Perl module [Cwd](http://perldoc.perl.org/Cwd.html) to accomplish this.  The link has an example also seen below.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use Cwd;
my $dir = getcwd;
use Cwd 'abs_path';
my $abs_path = abs_path($file);
```

Comment: This produces an absolute path, but it may still contain symlinks; e.g. you may not end up with a path that points from the root mount point of the filesystem the file is on.

Answer (score 3):

We can look from anywhere on the system, but in this case we're looking from the "/abc/def" folder.

```
$start_path = "/abc/def/";
@files = <$start_path*/myfile.txt>

foreach $file(@files) {
    print $file; # Prints the full path of the file.
}
```

Comment: This tries to match the glob `/abc/def/*/myfile.txt`, which in most places is going to look only one level below `def`. It looks like the OP doesn't know how many levels away it might be.

Answer (score -5):

Use `pwd` instead of `cd` in Linux to get path of current directory without function,

```
$path='cd';
$path =~ tr /\\/\//;
chomp($path);
print "$path";
```

Comment: Running the code as shown results in $path containing the literal string "cd". Were you expecting $path to contain the current working directory?